# Data gets duplicated in datagridview when query applied?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to perform CRUD operation on winform

This is for ASP.NET winform in which whenever I try to insert, update or delete the data to or from the database first of all rows and inside content gets duplicated
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkFY.jpg
however, upon restarting the application data shows up correctly

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //insert
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            //.text property gets/Sets text associated with this control

            String name = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            String address = textBox2.Text.ToString();

            String number = textBox3.Text.ToString();
            long pnumber = Int64.Parse(number);

            String sem = textBox4.Text.ToString();
            long semester = Int64.Parse(sem);

            string branch = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            String query = "insert into student values('" + name + "','" + address + "'," + pnumber + "," + semester + ",'" + branch + "')";
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            int i = sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (i >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student has been Registered: " + name);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registration Failed ! ");
            }
            //clearing data
            button1_Click(sender, e);
            show();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error is : " + exp.ToString());
        }
    }


   void show()
    {
        String query = "select * from student";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dataInTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataInTable);

        //DataRow represents row of data in DataTable
        foreach (DataRow item in dataInTable.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item[4].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The query works fine but rows still get duplicated. **What's the problem?**
 I can't find any bug, so I assume I am doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `show` method adds rows to the grid, but it never removes the rows which are already in the grid.

Normally one would use data binding to populate a `DataGridView` or other data-bound controls.  I'm going to assume you have reasons for just adding rows directly (perhaps it's simpler for your needs) and not change that.  Given that structure, probably the easiest thing to do is just to clear the grid before adding the new rows:

```
void show()
{
    String query = "select * from student";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dataInTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dataInTable);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); // <--- here

    foreach (DataRow item in dataInTable.Rows)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item[4].ToString();
    }
}
```

That way any time you are about to populate the grid with new data, you first clear the existing data from it.